# Must the radius of an open ball be real?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the metric space with $d(p,q) = |p-q|$. Is the radius of an open ball/a neighborhood of a point $p$ real, or in this case is it rational only? Thank you!

Comment: By definition, $d:\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\to[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: The distance between two rationals is rational, but a ball can have an irrational radius, in which case it will be open, and so will it's complement, in the metric topology, hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected.